# Non persistent installation of Windows (XP, Vista, 7)

Tags: windows, persistent

How do I install a non-persistent operating system (using Windows XP, Vista or 7)?

For example, all changes like testing updates should be automatically deleted as soon as the computer shuts off.

I know about ghosting and backup drives and that the OS can be virtualized, but is there anything else?

Comment: Why did your [similar Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556222/non-persistent-windows-os) actually include more details than this one?

Comment: Well, the answer I got wasn't nearly as good as the ones I got here. So obviously, I thought, I did something wrong. So I wrote it differently, do not think it has more information but more restrictions.

Comment: @slhck, Also, there is always a wonderful person like you to look out for me. :D

Comment: I see, well, for the future, it's always good to provide as many details as you can! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options available for doing this. The main is virtualization – I find this to be the best solution in my test instances.

Another (albeit more specific use product) would be steady state type of product. Check out [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/enterprise/deep-freeze/) for a good example.

> […] It protects your computer by freezing its original configuration, which prevents unwelcome or unwanted changes made while in-session from sticking. With a simple restore-to-reboot, your system integrity is maintained helping your machines to run smoothly and efficiently giving you more up-time and boosting user productivity

Comment: Microsoft Steady State is great, if you can still find the installer.

Comment: @slhck - thanks for the edit. I was planning to put a quote in place.

Comment: Sweet Can't use the virtualization as I do a lot of work with the drivers.

Comment: @Shinrai, Deep Freeze is apparently one of the replacements for the steady state as its being deprecated and also limited to 32bit xp and vista.

Comment: @RezaM. - Right, Steady State hasn't been available for some time now.  I mention it specifically as a first-party product for posterity.

Comment: Curious to know if there is a way to do deep freeze with the vmware non persistent feature. Well, It has the power for bootable vhd's, why not non-persistent VHD right ?

Answer (score 2):

**Sandboxie** runs apps in a protected environment so that any changes they make are non-permanent; this might be helpful to you in some circumstances and for quick testing.

http://www.sandboxie.com/

Comment: Really neat, Good to know about it. +1 but I require updates be made to other software so cannot let it be controlled so much. In short, it wouldn't allow me for the current task but this will be really useful in the future, thanks.